# How to fix: Shopify Cart Ajax API is always showing Sold out when adding a new variant

Tags: shopify, cart, shopify-api

I am developing an app to create product bundles. Firstly, I help customers to create a new variant with the quantity equals to 1 after selection. After that, I am using Cart ajax API to add this new variant to Cart. However, when I add the new variant with Fetch API, it's always showing sold out

> {status: 422, message: "Cart Error", description: "The product xxxx is already sold out."}

Here is the code to create new variant:

```
addBundleToCart() {
    console.log('length', this.variants.length);
    
    const url = '/create_new_variant/';
    
    let data = this.getRequestDataFromVariants(this.variants);
    data.bundleID = bundleID;

    let request = new Request(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {  
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    

    let vm1 = this;
    fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success creating variant:', data);
      console.log('variant_id:', data.variant_id);
      setTimeout(vm1.addNewVariantToCart(data.variant_id), 2000);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
    
  }
```

Here is the code to add the new variant to Cart (I copied from doc):

```
addNewVariantToCart(variant_id) {
    let formData = {
       'items': [{
        'id': parseInt(variant_id),
        'quantity': 1
        }]
      };
    
    fetch('/cart/add.js', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        //               'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success adding variant to cart:', data);
      //             console.log('Your bundle has been added to cart! Check your cart now.')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  }
```

When I run this code in the Chrome console by substituting the new variant id, it works without any problem. What's wrong here?